# Getting my internet setup to my Hp 4500 printer

Tags: unity

How can I set up my internet to my HP 4500 printer I have no choice for wireless wizard setup or something like that but I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not home so this is from memory.

1. Turn on the printer by pressing the power button.

   Press the Setup button.

   Use the <kbd>-></kbd> button and select "Setup Wizard."

   Follow the steps - easy, just "ok" for the most part.

   It will reach a point where it searches for wireless networks.

   Select your network.

   Using the controls, enter your password when prompted.

   Press <kbd>OK</kbd>

   You should now be able to find the printer over the network.

No special drivers are needed for standard functions, from memory. It should just work after that. Note: Not all the 4500 models actually support wireless connectivity, as I recall. Ensure that your model does by reading the owner's manual. The owner's manual will also go into any details I may have missed but I think that was all there was to it. Once configured you can, as I recall, also log into the control panel (and change any other settings) by way of connecting via the IP address. At home I have it locked so it is automatically: `http://192.168.1.101` with my browser of choice.